# Reseting CSS counter for nested lists formatted as 1.1, 1.2,

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to find a way in the CSS that I have...

https://jsfiddle.net/Lh0kLvj7/

```
    ol.content {
  counter-reset: item 1;
  list-style: none;
}

li.content:before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counter(item)". ";
}

ol.content ol.content li.content:before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
}

<p><span style="font-size: 24px;">On this page:</span></p>

<ol class="content">
  <li class="content"><a href="#">section TWO</a>

    <ol class="content">
      <li class="content"><a href="#section2-1">TWO point *ONE* (not 2.2!)</a></li>
      <li class="content"><a href="#section2-2">TWO point *TWO*</a></li>
      <li class="content"><a href="#section2-3">TWO point *THREE*</a></li>
      <li class="content"><a href="#section2-4">TWO point *FOUR*</a>

        <ol class="content">
          <li class="content">TWO point *FOUR* point *ONE* (not 2.5.2!)</li>
          <li class="content">Title...</li>
          <li class="content">Title...</li>
          <li class="content">Title...</li>
          <li class="content">Title...</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li class="content"><a href="#section2-5">TWO point *FIVE*</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

...to first start a parent counter sequence at a number that is not one (i.e., section 2 in the fiddle above), but have the nested lists actually start at .1.  I'm not great at CSS so it may be something simple that I'm missing. In the fiddle above you'll see that the HTML displays incorrectly...

2.

2.**2**

2.3

2.4

2.5

2.5.**2**

when I need...

2.

2.**1**

2.3

2.4

2.**4.1**

I definitely need to be able to start at any number for the initial/parent so I'm assuming I will have to use counter-reset: item 1;, counter-reset: item 2;, counter-reset: item 4;, etc. somewhere, but then I need to start nested lists should be reset to start at 1.

Comment: So you want to use more than one counter ... then do that, right now you are only using a single one.

Answer (score 3):

You're resetting your counter to 1:

```
ol.content {
  counter-reset: item 1;
  list-style: none;
}
```

If you reset it to 0 for nested lists it works as intended:

```
ol.content ol.content {
  counter-reset: item 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lh0kLvj7/3/

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  So simple I bet if you deal with CSS a lot.

Comment: No problem, that's what this website is for!

Answer (score 0):

You can re-assign the `counter-reset` for the second level menu like below.

```
 ol.content ol.content {
    counter-reset: item;
    list-style: none;
 }
```

**Code Snippet**

```css
ol.content {
  counter-reset: item 1;
  list-style: none;
}

li.content:before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counter(item)". ";
}
ol.content ol.content {
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style: none;
}

ol.content ol.content li.content:before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
}
```

```html
<p><span style="font-size: 24px;">On this page:</span></p>

<ol class="content">
  <li class="content"><a href="#">section TWO</a>

    <ol class="content">
      <li class="content"><a href="#section2-1">TWO point *ONE* (not 2.2!)</a></li>
      <li class="content"><a href="#section2-2">TWO point *TWO*</a></li>
      <li class="content"><a href="#section2-3">TWO point *THREE*</a></li>
      <li class="content"><a href="#section2-4">TWO point *FOUR*</a>

        <ol class="content">
          <li class="content">TWO point *FOUR* point *ONE* (not 2.5.2!)</li>
          <li class="content">Title...</li>
          <li class="content">Title...</li>
          <li class="content">Title...</li>
          <li class="content">Title...</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li class="content"><a href="#section2-5">TWO point *FIVE*</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why are you using ".content" classes everywhere... but anyway, easiest approach would be to use order classes on the OL tags

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
}

.f-o{
 counter-reset: f-o 1; 
/*initialized at 1 for demonstration purposes, you might want to start from zero*/
}

.s-o{
 counter-reset: s-o; 
}

.t-o{
  counter-reset:t-o;
}

.f-o li:before {
  content: counter(f-o)". ";
  counter-increment: f-o;

}

.s-o li:before {
  content: counter(f-o) "." counter(s-o)". ";
  counter-increment: s-o;
}

.t-o li:before {
  content: counter(f-o) "." counter(s-o)". " counter(t-o)". ";
  counter-increment: t-o;
}
```

```html
<ol class="f-o">
  <li><a href="#">section TWO</a>

    <ol class="s-o">
      <li><a href="#section2-1">TWO point *ONE* (not 2.2!)</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section2-2">TWO point *TWO*</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section2-3">TWO point *THREE*</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section2-4">TWO point *FOUR*</a>

        <ol class="t-o">
          <li>TWO point *FOUR* point *ONE* (not 2.5.2!)</li>
          <li>Title...</li>
          <li>Title...</li>
          <li>Title...</li>
          <li>Title...</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#section2-5">TWO point *FIVE*</a></li>
      </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

and attach the resets to them

Answer (score -2):

The solution is to use counter-reset property.

```
 ol.content ol.content {
   counter-reset: item 0;
 }
```

The counter-reset property is specified as either one of the following:

A *custom-ident* naming the counter, followed optionally by an *integer*. You may specify as many counters to reset as you want, with each name or name-number pair separated by a space.

The keyword value none.

Visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters

Comment: Please do not post answers that only rely on external links. The link could expire or it's contents could change. Capture the gist of the answer in the answer itself.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović i will keep these things in mind before posting an answer. Thanks. :)  . I have edited my answer as you suggested